# Mercurial API: How can I get the coming content of the file which was pulled but has not been updated yet?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-extension, mercurial-api

I'm a complete noob at Mercurial API and Python, but I'm trying to write a useful extension for myself and my colleagues now.

Let's assume I have a repository which contains some code and an auxiliary file `.hgdata`. The code and `.hgdata` are both under Mercurial's control. When I execute a command `pull-extended` which is provided by my extension, I want it to make a pull and then to analyze the state of a `.hgdata` and probably make some additional actions. The problem is that when my command is invoked, it just pulls the incoming changesets, but it can't look into the *actual* `.hgdata` without making a preceding repository update. Is there any way to watch the *after update* `.hgdata` besides repository update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've received an answer on the [Mercurial's official IRC channel](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/IRC):

In order to get an actual file state after making a pull, we may use `repo[revision][file].data()`.

P.S. I haven't checked that yet. If it works, I will close the question.